# Accessing a subfolder controller on resource route laravel 8

Tags: php

How can I access a subfolder controller on resource Route?
I have this structure of folders:
-Controllers
--Superadmin
---PermissionController.php

PermissionController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Superadmin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PermissionController extends Controller
{
}
```

I have tried some ways for this but still get the same error Target class was PermissionController was not found.

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('permission', 'Superadmin\PermissionController'); // 1
    Route::resource('permission', 'PermissionController'); // 2
    Route::resource('permission', App\Http\Controllers\Superadmin\PermissionController::class); //3
    Route::resource('permission', PermissionController::class); //4
)}
```

Here are all the solutions I have tried. I also added the `use App\Http\Controllers\Superadmin\PermissionCotnroller` when I tried solution number 4. Can't find the problem.

Comment: This approach appears rather questionable and the actual intent is not being explained. I mean, what do you need four different controllers, which all merely do the same thing?

Comment: I showed all the solutions I tried and none of them worked, because I know I need just one controller. Here are 4 ways I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `namespace` parameter to the group, like so:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Superadmin','middleware'=>'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('permission', 'PermissionController'); // 2
}
```